# Thread Safe Document creation in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, mongodb, thread-safety, mongoid

I am trying to use Sidekiq workers to perform some background tasks.

Sidekiq **really** emphasises on making the jobs thread-safe. The workers will basically be updating Mongoid Documents using `#inc()`, which is atomic (and hence thread-safe). But before the actual update they will also perform a `Model.find_or_create_by` call, which is not atomic (it is equal to separate `QUERY` and `INSERT` ops).

Am I right in thinking this can lead to race-condition - 2 workers running together, will both perform a `QUERY` (which will fail for both) and then a `INSERT` (which will succeed for one but fail for the other, because my model has indexes with uniqueness clause)

To avoid the above, I have wrapped the find_or_create_by in a begin-rescue clause:

```
begin
    x = A.find_or_create_by(...)
rescue
    x = A.find_by(...)
end
```

Is this the correct approach, or is there a simpler way to create Mongoid Documents in a thread safe way?

Edit: I have seen [Is find_or_create_by thread safe in Mongoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072866/is-find-or-create-by-thread-safe-in-mongoid?rq=1), but it doesn't give a solution, it just confirms that find_create_by is not thread safe.